# Eclipse not accepting parametrized type in library

Tags: eclipse, type-conversion, java, type-mismatch

I have written a short class with the http://www.ow2.org/view/ActivitiesDashboard/ASM library. Eclipse (Version: 4.3.1
Build id: M20130911-1000) marks the marked statement as an error ("**Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to FieldNode**"). I'm compiling with **jre7**. This is incorrect as the source-code of the used jar shows. But first of all here is my class source:

```
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode;
public class AccessTransformer
{
ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();

public byte[] transform(String name, String transformedName, byte[] bytes)
{

    for (FieldNode n : this.classNode.fields) // <----- HERE IS THE ERROR
    {
        if (n.name.equals("test"))
        {
            n.access = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The jar though states (class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode):

```
/**
 * The fields of this class. This list is a list of {@link FieldNode}
 * objects.
 * 
 * @associates org.objectweb.asm.tree.FieldNode
 */
public List<FieldNode> fields;
```

Does anyone have an idea what I may have done wrong? How can I assure that eclipse "sees" the parametrized type of the list as FieldNode?

I try not to use refletion because it would slow the process down for nothing. I could introduce an "unsafe" cast but the problem is more meta, I wonder why eclipse shows "type mismatch".

Comment: what is the actual type of the fields List (eg. arrayList, LinkedList, etc)?

Comment: What version of java are you compiling with?

Comment: If you are trying to retrieve just the declared fields, I'd try using reflection -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful

Comment: Mark W: I would have to look that up..., edthethird: 1.7.0, Ashish: reflection is slow ...